# user-defined type not defined "WithEvents MSForms.ComboBox"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to declare a variable with this line : `"Private WithEvents mclsCbx As MSForms.ComboBox"` and I get this error : 
"user-defined type not defined". How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have a class called `CControlEvents` in your workbook? I suspect not...

Comment: I did a mistake in my post, please look at my last edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library. Inserting a userform (you can then delete it) is usually the quickest way.